# Combinatorics homework

Tags: combinatorics

Here's a question from my homework. First 2 questions I solved (but would appreciate any input you can give on my solution) and the last question I'm just completely stumped. It's  quite complicated.

On the shelf there are 5 math books, 3 science fiction books and 2 thrillers (**all of the books are different**)

1) In how many different combinations can you organize the books on the shelf, without any limitation? **My answer: $10!$ since all the books are different, it's just organizing 10 books.

2) In how many different combinations can you organize the books so that books of the same kind are next to each other? **My answer: $3!*5!*3!*2!$ - first imagine all the math books are just 1 block, all the sci fi books are 1 block, and that the 2 thrillers are 1 block. I have $3!$ ways to organize these blocks on the shelf. The $5!*3!*2!$ is due to the order of the books inside the block.

3) How many different combinations are there to organize the books such that the sci fi books are together, and there is at least 1 book inbetween the thrillers?
**My answer: I don't know. It's too complex. I thought maybe simplying it by saying at least 1 book  in between = combinations with 1 book in between + combinations with 2 books etc but even that doesn't make it any simpler...

Help? :)

Comment: Do you have access to the correct answer? It seems as though everyone is getting different results. I, for one, am getting $8!*3!-9*2*6!*3!$, which is between the two other answers.

Comment: No I don't. The teacher from my university just uploaded this today, so I will only have answers next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, let's see how many ways we can put other books around the thrillers, ignoring distinctions between books of the same type. To begin with, we are going to have two thrillers, with space between and to either side:

$$\text{_T_T_}$$

Now, we must put another book in between them. There are two cases to consider, here.

---

**Case 1: There are no sci-fi books between the thrillers.**

After placing the sci-fi-books, our arrangement is one of the following:

$$\text{_SSS_T_T_}$$

$$\text{_T_T_SSS_}$$

In either case, we *must* place a math book in between the thrillers, so our possible arrangements are:

$$\text{_SSS_T_M_T_}$$

$$\text{_T_M_T_SSS_}$$

Now we have $4$ more math books to place. Note that if we put a math book next to the math book we've already placed, then it doesn't really matter which side we put it on (as far as distinguishing between these arrangements), so these arrangements can be thought of as:

$$\text{_SSS_T_MT_}$$

$$\text{_T_MT_SSS_}$$

Any or all of the $4$ remaining math books can be placed in any of the remaining $4$ slots, so there are $2\cdot 4^4$ arrangements of $3$ $\text{S}$s, $5$ $\text{M}$s, and $2$ $\text{T}$s in which the $\text{T}$s are not consecutive, the $\text{S}$s are consecutive, and the $\text{S}$s are not between the $\text{T}$s.

---

**Case 1: There are sci-fi books between the thrillers.**

Since we must place the sci-fi books in a block, then our arrangement is:

$$\text{_T_SSS_T_}$$

Any or all of the $5$ math books can be placed in the remaining $4$ slots, so there are $4^5$ arrangements of $3$ $\text{S}$s, $5$ $\text{M}$s, and $2$ $\text{T}$s in which the $\text{T}$s are not consecutive, the $\text{S}$s are consecutive, and the $\text{S}$s are between the $\text{T}$s.

---

Between the two cases, we have $2\cdot 4^4+4^5=1536$ arrangements of $3$ $\text{S}$s, $5$ $\text{M}$s, and $2$ $\text{T}$s in which the $\text{T}$s are not consecutive, but the $\text{S}$s are consecutive. Now, all that remains is to order the books in each category. There are $5!3!2!$ ways to do this, and so we have $1536\cdot 5!3!2!$ arrangements of the given type.

Comment: There are only 3 SciFi books, not 5.

Comment: Oops! Switched the math and sci-fi numbers. I will fix it now.

Comment: Thanks for the very in depth answer Cameron! "Either or both of the 4 remaining math books can be placed in any of the remaining 4 slots, so there are 2⋅44 " can you just quickly explain why this is true? I kinda lost you there

Comment: @Oria: It's because there is no condition on whether the math books have to be all together, all apart, or in clusters. We can place the rest of them anywhere we wish on the shelf, since we've already taken care of the requirements that the sci-fi books must be together and the thrillers apart.

Comment: No no I understand that. What I don't understand is why you multiplied $4^4$ by 2. There are 4 open spaces, and 4 math books. Where did the 2 come from

Comment: @Oria: The $2$ came from the fact that we had both $\text{_SSS_T_MT_}$ and $\text{_T_MT_SSS_}$ as options. We multiplied by $4^4$ because in both of those scenarios, we had $4$ choices for each of the remaining $4$ math books.

Comment: Ah yes I see, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

If the sci-fi books are together, consider them a single element again that can be permuted ($3!$) times and thus the eight books (with three being considered one book) have 6! rearrangements. If there is at least one book in between the thrillers, then there are (2!9) permutations where the thrillers aren't separated by a book. Thus, we have $3!6!8 - 2!9$.

Comment: I don't understand. I get the "think of the sci fi books as a single element", but I don't understand the $6!$ part and the $2!9$

Comment: $X, X, X, X, X, Y, Y, Y$ where $X$ is your math books and $Y$ is your science books. Notice we require that the sci-fi books are together, so that's a group of three books, namely $Y$. Let $Y_0$ be the group of $Y$. Then $X, X, X, X, X, Y_0$ has 6! rearrangements and the sci-fi books have 3!.

Comment: You are right ofcourse. thank you. It's late :)